# How to hide the Navigation Bar (on the iPhone X) in Flutter

Tags: ios, dart, flutter, iphone-x

How do I hide the navigation bar, which was introduced to *iOS with the iPhone X* in Flutter?

[image: iPhone X screen capture]

In the image I would want to hide the white bar at the bottom, which is the standard navigation bar for the new iOS version.

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Comment: Ive tried searching for it but cannot find anything useful at all. Hence why I am asking here.

Comment: @AshleyMills What more information do you expect?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot At least something on how to hide the home indicator. I don't want to just put widgets on top of it. In swift, we override `prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden`

Comment: I was defending your post in the regards @AshleyMills critized because I felt like the information you provided was enough.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I realised after the post. Sorry about that. Read it too quickly.

Answer (score 3):

In Flutter, [`SystemChrome`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemChrome-class.html) takes care of it.
The function [`setEnabledSystemUIOverlays`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51993256/hide-home-bar-indicator-on-iphone-x) takes a `List` of the enum [`SystemUiOverlay`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemUiOverlay-class.html), i.e. `SystemUIOverlay.bottom`, `SystemUIOverlay.top`, both or none at all.

For your specific case I suggest that calling it in the `main` function should work fine for a start:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);
runApp(...);
```

As you can see, I *only provided **`SystemUIOverlay.top`***, which will consequently *disable* the bottom part of the system's UI overlay, which is the home indicator on your the new iOS navigation and also the navigation of Android, which is going to be hidden.

I am not aware of all runtime scenarios on iOS, which means that you might need to call `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top])` more often or even provide no elements to the list if full screen mode is required to hide the system navigation.

Comment: Thanks for answering. That didn't fix my issue though. See the updated post for more information. I also tried it without the .bottom.

Comment: @iProgram My second suggestion should have obviously been to provide an empty `List`, like this: `[]`.

Comment: @iProgram Check this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20965

Comment: Thanks for posting it as an issue. So looks like I can't hide it at the moment them. Ive replied back incase other people need to ask questions on the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I made [a package to do this](https://pub.dev/packages/home_indicator): add `home_indicator` to your pubspec.yaml, then

```dart
import 'package:home_indicator/home_indicator.dart';

await HomeIndicator.hide();
```

Comment: How does this work, didn't work for me.