# Flutter - How to remove BottomAppBar Padding?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

[image: The solid grey portion at the bottom]

I need to remove the solid grey padding at the bottom.

```
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          
          color: Colors.grey.shade200.withOpacity(0.8),
          elevation: 0,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          notchMargin: 5,
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          child: Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: Wrap(
              children: [
                Container(
                  //color: Colors.transparent,
                  height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.1,
                  child: ClipRect(
                    child: BackdropFilter(
                      filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                        sigmaX: blur,
                        sigmaY: blur,
                      ),
                      child: BottomNavigationBar(
                        iconSize: 55,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                        currentIndex: 0,
                        onTap: (int index) {},
                        items: [
                          BottomNavigationBarItem(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.radio), label: 'A'),
                          BottomNavigationBarItem(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.radio), label: 'A'),
                          BottomNavigationBarItem(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.radio), label: 'A'),
                          BottomNavigationBarItem(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.radio), label: 'A'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

I am not using SafeArea, yet there is this padding (I inspected with Widget inspector) of 34 that is getting applied to the BottomAppBar.

Comment: Does `extendBody: true` have any effect  or `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,`

Comment: No, extendBody: true changes the opacity of the extended (solid grey) portion; meaning the body is now extended and is visible behind the BottomAppBar. extendBodyBehindAppBar: true changes the AppBar(top) which is irrelevant here. I tried all that.

Comment: cant test ios , but I think I've seen some logic on Scaffold for ios specific, I will share if i get it

Comment: Cant find that, try https://stackoverflow.com/q/51993256/10157127

Comment: Yes, it's an iOS specific issue. The link doesn't provide a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I removed some widgets that looked obsolete, but here you go:

```js
Scaffold(
  ...,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  extendBody: true,
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    notchMargin: 5,
    color: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0,
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge, // <========== This is important!
    child: BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(
        sigmaX: 5,
        sigmaY: 5,
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        iconSize: 55,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: 0,
        elevation: 0,
        onTap: (index) {},
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.radio), label: 'A'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.radio), label: 'A'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.radio), label: 'A'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.radio), label: 'A'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image: Final Screenshot]

Comment: I also need the BottomNavBar to be notched; this doesn't achieve that.

Comment: Alright, I updated my example. In that case, the nesting of `BottomAppBar` and `BottomNavigationBar` is probably the easiest solution. Pay attention to the `clipBehavior`, it defaults to `Clip.none`.

Comment: This almost works except that the bottom padding of the BottomAppBar (the initial problem) is clickable; meaning if have something like a button behind the BottomNavBar,  it is clickable from the extra padding(only in iOS) at the bottom.

Comment: BTW, any idea how those icons can be middle aligned vertically?

Comment: In my example app, the area below the buttons is not clickable - please check your implementation, you posted only a very small piece of code. For the alignment - the padding is added by the `BottomNavigationBar` . You could replace it with a simple `Row` and add some buttons to it but would lose the "Label Magic" etc.

Comment: Another workaround: Move your `BottomNavigationBar` slightly down (`Transform.translate(offset: const Offset(0, 10),child: ... ),`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249627/discussion-between-who-aditya-nawandar-and-robdil).